# Accepting List<MultipartFile> files from Angular

Tags: angular, spring, file-upload

I'm experiencing issue with sending multiple files from angular front-end to spring-boot backend. I've tried everything from stack and from net but i couldn't find the answer. Here's my code:

Angular:
.ts file:

```
  submit(){
    this.uploadedFiles = this.uploadedFiles.map(item => {
      let formData = new FormData();
      return formData.append('file',item,item.name);
    });
    this.service.postFile(this.uploadedFiles).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    })
  }
```

**this.uploadedFiles is somehow undefined of type FormData ?**

[image]

service file:

```
postFile(files: any): Observable<string>{
      return this.http.post('/id/file', files, {responseType:'text'});
  }
```

spring controller:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/file")
private String newFile(@RequestBody List<MultipartFile> mf) {
    return "error";
}
```

inside of debugger i've got null for mf list.

The main issue is that for 1 file (when I'm using only MultipartFile) mine code is working.

I'm using PrimeNG's p-fileupload with custom upload event.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with you sending an Array of `FormData` instances to `postFile` since you're instantiating `formData` again and again inside the `map`.

Give this a try to see if this works:

```
submit() {
  const formData = new FormData();
  this.uploadedFiles = this.uploadedFiles.map(item => formData.append('file', item, item.name));
  this.service.postFile(this.uploadedFiles).subscribe(result => console.log(result));
}
```

**PS:** I haven't tested this out but I feel it should work.

#### UPDATE:

I think you're logging the `formData` to the console like this:

```
console.log(files);
```

In your `postFile` method.

OR:

```
console.log(formData);
```

In your Component.

What you should be doing instead is

```
console.log(formData.get('file'));
```

Comment: it returns undefined aswell

Comment: I've tried it like you've said and I'm getting for 2 files, 2 File objects containing name, lastModified, type...

Comment: Yeah I mean for two selected files, it is going to show two File Objects in an array. What exactly did you expect?